# yt-dlp is downloading videos from a playlist as .webm files instead of .mp3 files

Tags: batch-file, yt-dlp

I'm running a `.bat` script on Windows 10 that uses `yt-dlp.exe`, to download files and put them into a created directory.

This is what the code currently looks like, with `yt-dlp.exe`, `downloaded.txt`, and `ffmpeg.exe` in the same directory:

```batch-file
F:
cd \Desktop\Youtube DLP
set /P id=Enter Playlist or Video URL: 
set /P output=Enter Name Your Output folder:
yt-dlp.exe --yes-playlist %id% --ignore-errors --download-archive 
downloaded.txt --no-post-overwrites -ciwx --audio-format mp3
md %output%
move *.mp3 %output%
echo files are done
pause
```

Even with what I believe to be the right settings for it to run properly, it isn't downloading .mp3, but .webm files instead. Could someone point me to what might be wrong?

Comment: Not every program allows you to merge single-character options like that. What happens if you split `-ciwx` into `-c -w -i -x`?

Comment: Also, I've now tested your code and it gives the correct end result with .mp3 files ending up on my machine. The files are initially downloaded as .webm because that's how YouTube stores them, but they get converted to .mp3 once they're downloaded. No .mp3 files are downloaded because there are no .mp3 files to download.

Answer (score 1):

A possible fix would be to update the output template to reflect what you want by outputting `%output%\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s`

It also might be the case that `yt-dlp` doesn't know it has to use `ffmpeg` for post-processing. Might as well add the extra command `--extract-audio`

Ensure both `yt-dlp` and `ffmpeg` are up to date.